# -bash: sudo: command not found with godaddy

Tags: redhat, sudo

I'm trying to install ElasticSearch with godaddy hosting, but it's keep getting me this error:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found 

echo $PATH
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/bingoladmin/.local/bin:/home/bingoladmin/bin
```

Linux distribution Red hat

Comment: Is the sudo package installed?

Comment: how can I see if is it installed ? plz

Comment: `yum list installed sudo` should show one installed package, or show a message like "no package named sudo found"

Comment: it's giving me "-bash: yum: command not found
"

Comment: try `rpm -q sudo`

Comment: the same probleme "-bash: rpm: command not found"

Comment: I find it impossible that you are running Redhat with neither `yum` nor `rpm`.

Comment: I'm sure that is Red hat distribution, when I try "cat /proc/version" it's show me //Linux version 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu May 5 16:06:47 EDT 2016
//

Comment: Thanks for you help, apparently it's shared hosting so I don’t have root access !!